# What's the most minimalistic way to render "OK" in Elixir/Phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

In Rails you can render text directly, e.g. `render :text => 'OK'`

Is there a shortcut in Elixir/Phoenix to render text directly, without having to define a template or layout?

The shortest way I found was this:

```
  defmodule MyApp.PageController do
    use MyApp.Web, :controller

    def index(conn, _params) do
      # the file ok.html.eex contains just the string OK
      render conn, "ok.html", layout: false
    end
  end
```

Is there a shorter way to render "OK", without having to provide the template file "ok.html"?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers:

> ### Rendering
>
> Controllers have several ways of rendering content. The
>   simplest is to render some plain text using the `text/2` function
>   which Phoenix provides.
>
> Let's say we have a show action which receives an id from the params
>   map, and all we want to do is return some text with the id. For that,
>   we could do the following.
>
> ```
> def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
>   text conn, "Showing id #{id}"
> end
> ```

Comment: awesome! thanks! looks like I was looking at the wrong place in the docs (under render)

Comment: Is there a way to set encoding for to `html`?

Comment: I guess `html/2` function would be the way to go then.

Comment: @Anatoly Just scroll down a little to `html/2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I render text to check if my route is working before using a template.

```
def show(conn, _params) do
  text conn, "Display OK"
end
```